# How to import other Sequelize models in a model for Class methods. Sequelize v 5

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to define Class Methods in Sequelize Models like this

```
const db = require('../models');
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Product = sequelize.define('Product', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,

    categoryId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: sequelize.Category,
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
 }, {});
  Product.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Product.belongsTo(models.Category, {foreignKey: 'categoryId', as: 'category'});
    Product.hasMany(models.ProductPacking, {foreignKey: 'productId', as: 'packings'});
    Product.hasMany(models.ProductAnimal, {foreignKey: 'productId', as: 'animals'});
  };

  /*Returns all products who have active packings with details*/
  Product.getAllWithPackings = function(onlyProductsWithPacking = false) {
    return Product.findAll({include: [
        {
          model: db.ProductPacking,
          as: 'packings',
          where: {isActive: true},
          required: onlyProductsWithPacking,
          attributes: ['name', 'price', 'id', 'image'],
        },
        {
          model: db.Category,
          as: 'category',
          attributes: ['name', 'id'],
          include: {
            model: db.Category,
            as: 'parentCategory',
            attributes: ['name', 'id'],
          }
        },
        {
          model: db.ProductAnimal,
          as: 'animals',
          attributes: ['name']
        }
      ]}).then(resp => {
        return Promise.resolve(resp);
    });
  };


  return Product;
};
```

However when I run the class method 'getAllWithPacking()', I get the error `Include unexpected. Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object.`

The associations are defined correctly and the same function will give the expected result in a controller. The issue here is that the constant 'db' is empty in that function. If I `const db = require('../models');` inside the class method, the function runs fine.

Is there something that I may be missing here?

Comment: Does `const db = require('../models');` contain a registration of a Product model as well?

Comment: @Anatoly Yes, it does

Comment: I recommend to move this method outside (something like ProductRepository module that may contain all CRUD and related operations with Product model) or to pass models into it instead of using `db`.

Comment: I may end up writing many class and instance methods, and many would use data from associations. Is this not possible in sequelize or not the recommended way?

Comment: I suppose this is not recommended way. Nevertheless you can try to use the `sequelize` static prop of a model to access all models you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the model's sequelize instance, and hence the other models, through `this._modelOptions.sequelize`.

But if you can do it using associations, do, as otherwise some additional features (such as transactions) may not behave correctly. At least, not without some additional tinkering.

```
let { sequelize = { models } } = this._modelOptions;

[...]
    model: models.Name,
[...]
```

```
let { sequelize = { models } } = this._modelOptions;
let result = await models.ModelName.findAll()
```

Comment: (In 6.0, replace `this._modelOptions` with `this.constructor.options`)